# Run certain Jenkins jobs alone on a node

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

There some Jenkins jobs that have very high memory requirements. With the aim to avoid memory-related issues I'd like to configure these jobs to block execution of any other jobs from any project on the same node while they are running.

I played with [Throttle Concurrent Builds Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Throttle+Concurrent+Builds+Plugin), but it looks to limit jobs only from the same project. Other plugin - [Build Blocker Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Build+Blocker+Plugin) doesn't block other jobs to be run while the configured job is running.

Are there any plugins that allow to configure "single process" mode for some jobs?

Comment: I would try configure this node with single executor, so you'll get no concurrency between jobs at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the "Throttle Concurrent Builds" Plugin there is a "Multi-Project Throttle Categories" option. Make a category "memory hogs" and add all jobs using a lot of memory to that category, than configure limits with "Throttle this project as part of one or more categories"

Comment: Thanks arved. However this doesn't prevent jobs that are not in the "memory hogs" category to run simultaneously with "memory hogs" jobs.

Comment: Ok, then maybe "Exclusive Execution Plugin"is for you? (have not tried this myself)

Comment: "Exclusive Execution Plugin" looks like a hack with its entering shutdown phase but at least it does what I'm trying to archive.
Thanks again arved.

Comment: @ValeryC how do I use this in a pipeline? Any code samples?